# Lenovo G50-45 GFX recognition issue

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics, amd-processor

I own the above mentioned laptop. I was running Win 8.1 x64 OEM on it up until recently when I decided to go back to Ubuntu.

The problem is on Windows with latest drivers it nicely detected, that I have both an AMD R4 w/ 1 GB VRAM and an AMD R5 w/ 2 GB VRAM installed.

On Ubuntu with latest Catalyst installed from AMD's website it shows only AMD R4. inxi -F gave the following output:

```
 Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics] 
           X.Org: 1.16.0 driver: fglrx Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon R4 Graphics GLX Version: 4.4.13283 - CPC 14.501.1003
```

Is there a way to get most of my system again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 15.04 might resolve this, as doing a brief check with a LiveUSB running both Ubuntu GNOME and Xubuntu w/ kernel 3.19.* confirms both cards being detected with drivers out of the box.